# How get parent div

Tags: jquery

Good day.

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
</div>
<div class="form-group has-warning">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning">
</div>
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError">
</div>
```

I would like that when input lose focus (`focusout`) in class element div with class `form-group` add class `add`, but only one.

For ex. if input with `id=inputError` loses focus in class element `<div class="form-group has-error">` add class `add`:  `<div class="form-group has-error add">`

And I would like that only in one element with class `form-group` add class "add".

I use code:

```
$(".form-control").focusout(function(){

})
```

but I don't know how get parent div with class `form-group`...

How make this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find out the nearest ancestor element matching the given selector

```
$(".form-control").focusout(function(){
    var $div = $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('add')
})
```

in you case if the `form-group` element is always the direct parent of `form-control` element then you can even use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(".form-control").focusout(function(){
    var $div = $(this).parent().addClass('add')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method

```
$(".form-control").focusout(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('add');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".form-control").focusout(function(){
   $(this).parent('.form-group').addClass('add');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$(".form-control").on('focusout', function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('add');
});
```

or this one

```
$(".form-control").on('focusout', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('add');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".form-control").focusout(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('add');
})
```